# Where does UIViewController keep its fromInterfaceOrientation info?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I need to make adjustments to a layer when the iPhone is rotated, but only if it is rotated from portrait to landscape or vice versa. I don’t need to do anything if it is rotated from landscapeLeft 180 degrees to landscapeRight, or from portrait 180 degrees to portraitUpsideDown.

So in order to avoid unnecessary action, I run a test like this (`self` is the view controller):

```c
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    BOOL bFromPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);
    BOOL bToPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation);    
    if (bFromPortrait != bToPortrait)
            // make adjustments
}
```

Which doesn’t work, because by the time `willAnimate` is called, `self.interfaceOrientation` has already been changed to reflect the new orientation, so bFromPortrait and bToPortrait are always the same and the adjustments never happen.

So I tried running this code from `willRotate`, at which point “the interfaceOrientation property still contains the view’s original orientation.” But at that point the layer’s host view’s autosize adjustments have not yet been made, so I have no way to access the auto-resized frame it will have for the target orientation, without which I cannot make my adjustments.

So I added a boolean property `bFromPortrait` in order to keep track of which orientation the iPhone was coming from, set it in `willRotate`, and accessed it in `willAnimate` (this works):

```c
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    self.bFromPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(self.interfaceOrientation);    
}

- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    BOOL bToPortrait = UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation);
    if (self.bFromPortrait != bToPortrait)  
        // Make adjustments.
}
```

But I noticed that if I overrode `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`, its `fromInterfaceOrientation` arg correctly reflected where the iPhone was coming from, even though this method is called *after* the others. **So that extra boolean property `bFromPortrait` should not be necessary; UIViewController is already keeping track of this info — but where? How do I access it?**

(You might ask, why not make the adjustments in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`. The problem is that this method runs after the animation, so the adjustments snap. In order for the adjustments to be included in the animation, they must happen in `willAnimate`.)

Answer (score 1):

You may be over thinking this a bit :)

I had a similar issue; this is the code that I used to solve the problem:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
    CGRect rect;

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.height, size.width);
    } 
    else
    {
        rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    }

    // Views that need updating        
    clockFaceView.frame = rect;
    hourIndicatorView.frame = rect;
    minuteIndicatorView.frame = rect;
    // Update viewControllers
    [timeInWordsOverlayController updateBoundsWithRect:rect];
    [actionOveralyViewController updateBoundsWithRect:rect];
}
```

where `updateBoundsWithRect` is defined as:

```
- (void) updateBoundsWithRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    _actionView.frame = rect;
    self.view.frame = rect;
}
```

You download the the free app and see the result of the code. [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/app/clock-tutor/id509832070) link.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Well, I don't think you're exactly addressing the issue of how to differentiate between 90 and 180 degree rotations, but your code does suggest another way of keeping track: a CGSize property. The new width and height would differ from the cached size only for 90-degree rotations. Portrait vs landscape could be determined by the width/height ratio. But I think the boolean is simpler.

Comment: The main problem, getting things to work, is solved in the second code  example in the question, as a work-around. The little problem, what I was asking, was why that work-around should be necessary at all. The info is already held by UIViewController, so it would nice to be able to access it directly.